# I am having trouble getting Phusion Passenger to run on OS X Yosemite

Tags: passenger, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded my MacBook to Yosemite, and now passenger no longer seems to work.  Every time I try to restart Apache, I get this error in the logs:

```
[ 2014-10-19 17:08:51.6913 9735/0x7fff7b970300 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.9726/generation-0/request
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/barry.flinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@sermo/gems/passenger-4.0.53/buildout/agents/PassengerLoggingAgent
Reason: Incompatible library version: PassengerLoggingAgent requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

When I run `otool -L /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`, I get:

```
/opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
    /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.12.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

However, the system version `/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib` gives:

```
/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 57031.1.27)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1151.14.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

As near as I can tell, even though I built mod_passenger against `/opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`, it is still trying to run using the lib at `/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`.  I am stuck trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist). I had the same problem after upgrading to Yosemite and the solution for me was to unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (which is one of the solutions suggested by macports)